# How to append an object and its material at once?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, objects, append

I'd like to append an object and its material at the same time. When I try to append an object then the material is not applied to object.

*How can I append both at once?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As first - assign materials to objects and when you append this objects to new scene, they will append with materials. If you append materials separately, Blender can't know which material assign to which object.

Comment: Thanks i forgot to switch to cycles render so the material i was unable to view